# IFrame form submittal opens in frame, needs to open in new window

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

Trying to resolve an issue using a 3rd party form that unfortunately has to use an iframe to be embedded in the article content. When a user submits their email address, the thank you page opens up in the space taken up by the iframe instead of the page / a new window. I tried using the following JS script to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// If "&_parent=URL" is in this page's URL, then put URL into the top window
var match = /_parent=(.+)/.exec(window.location.href);
if (match != null) {
top.location = match[1];
}
</script>
```

The page in question:

http://restoringqualityoflifeblog.org/subscribe/

Thanks!

Comment: It is really tough to edit what is happening inside of the iframe itself. It may be easier to look at how the form itself is submitting to the server, and mimic that with your own form

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.salsalabs.com/entries/21689130-Embed-a-signup-form
Here is the form you need by itself with [] indicating the keys you need for it to work.

```
<form action="[[API URL]]/save" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="organization_KEY" value="5881"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="chapter_KEY" value="887"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="email_trigger_KEYS" value="12644,12656"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="object" value="supporter"/>
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label><input type="text" id="first_name" name="First_Name"/></br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="last_name" name="Last_Name"/></br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" id="email" name="Email"/></br>
    <style>.memberCode{display:none;}</style>
    <div class="memberCode"> Optional Member Code <input name="first_name_949" value=""/></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="groups"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="linkKey" value="11"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="groups"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="linkKey" value="12"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="groups"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="linkKey" value="13"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tag" value="excellent"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://YOUR URL">
    <input type="Submit" value="Sign up" />
</form>
```

You already have a working copy of the form here:
http://salsa3.salsalabs.com/o/50047/p/salsa/web/common/public/signup?signup_page_KEY=8896

Comment: I thought I could just take the code from the working copy (the 2nd URL) and add it to the article, but when I do it redirects to the salsa page hosting the form. (the 2nd submit form) They are quite adamant about using an IFrame - frustrating.

Comment: Try looking at that first link. It sure looks like they allow you to set it up as your own form on the page.

Comment: This may be useful as well : http://www.richiroutreach.com/blog/how-embed-salsa-sign-form-your-wordpress-page